# Throw into the database as it looks in HTML form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

It is such that I have to "update" the database with new content and I print it in pure HTML, but when I throw it into the database with the HTML as it has allocated so that it will in no way throw it into the database

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult index(IndholdViewModel model)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
        var forsideindhold = db.forsides.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1);
         if (forsideindhold != null)
          {
           //error here
             forsideindhold.tekst = new HtmlString(model.Indhold);
              .SubmitChanges();
               return RedirectToAction("index/Opdater");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Error happens here:

```
forsideindhold.tekst = new HtmlString(model.Indhold);
```

What I well only imagine this is that it remove the HTML it has got hold of by my model.indhold and throw it into the database.

Error are:

> cannot convert from 'System.Web.HtmlString' to 'string'

[image]

Comment: show the error please

Comment: @teovankot i have edit its now.

Comment: Try `forsideindhold.tekst = model.Indhold.ToString();`

Comment: The point is `HtmlString` and `String` is 2 different classes.

Comment: Try this - `(new HtmlString(model.Indhold)).ToString()`

Comment: @ramiramilu make it same error on it.

Comment: @JesperPetersen what type `Indhold`?

Comment: try this - `(new HtmlString(model.Indhold.ToString())).ToString()`

Comment: see here @teovankot http://postimg.org/image/7avmz09bb/

Answer (score 0):

Well your problem is that you can't pass to `HtmlString` constructor `HtmlString`.

But actually i can't understand why you need it as long as  `forsideindhold.tekst` is `string`. You should write it like this:

```
forsideindhold.tekst = model.Indhold.ToString();
```

Or:

```
forsideindhold.tekst = new HtmlString(model.Indhold.ToString()).ToString();
```

Comment: Error are now: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @JesperPetersen that means that you have null in your `Indhold` or event in `model`.

Comment: yea, Indhold are null. hmm but it comes out content in textbox

Comment: @JesperPetersen show your View part of this property

Answer (score 0):

check your value is null or not before insert to model.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Indhold)) forsideindhold.tekst = new HtmlString(model.Indhold.ToString()).ToString();
```